# Three.js | "Cannot read property 'set' of undefined" error while traversing .obj file consist of 'o' tags

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to update the color of an object at run time. It was going well until I replaced the object file with the one that has 'o' tags in .obj file.

Now, I'm receiving this in console.[image: error in console]

here's my code.

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.setPath( 'obj/Nissan/' );
mtlLoader.load( 'nissan-gt-r-nismo-1.mtl', function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.setPath( 'obj/test/' );
    objLoader.load( 'lol.obj', function( object ) {

        object.scale.set(100,100,100);
        object.traverse( function( child ) { 
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 
                child.material.color.set(0xffffff); //this.
                console.log(child.material.color); // also, this is returning 'undefined'
            }    
        } );
    scene.add( object );
    });
});
```

Also, `console.log` is returning 'undefined' as if it can't find the color property of material.

What I'm doing wrong? 
How do I traverse through 'o' tags and find the material.color property?

Edit : 
All I can find about the object's material is this :[image: Material properties]

No, color property. How should I find it or traverse through 'o' tags to find it?

Comment: You can look at `console.log(child.material);` and see the type of the material and the other properties.

Comment: There's no color property. That is what I'm asking how to traverse the child node of 'o' objects so that I can find the `color` property.

Comment: What type of the material do you get in console log?

Comment: Just mentioned it in the question. Hope that helps. @prisoner849

Comment: The `materials` propery is an array of materials, isn't it?

Comment: MultiMaterial doesn't have a color, it has multiple materials that have colors.

Comment: What are `'o' objects`?

Comment: @pailhead Ya I learned that in console. How can I traverse to those material in multimaterial?
'o' tags are object tags, you can read about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)

Comment: @prisoner849 yes, it is. Can you help me in traversing through it so I can reach `material.color`

Comment: Using  of `for` or `forEach()` loops will help to run through the _array_ of materials.

Comment: I like forEach()

Comment: @prisoner849 Ya I know `for` or `forEach()` will help to run through array. I was asking how to achieve it. In array, should I look for `material.color` only or just `color`.

Comment: Something like this: `child.MultiMaterial.materials.forEach( function( material ){ material.color.setHex( 0xffffff ); } );`

Comment: Okay, let me give this a try. I also found another method. If any of these works I'll let you know.